# Creating custom reusable method in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Guys today I'm trying to create global method for all my project models in rails 4

I created something like that under this path `lib/query.rb`

```
module Query

  def custom my_query
    self.where(my_query)
  end

end
```

then added this code in this file `lib/application.rb` to allow rails to load the files under this path

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

then included my method in my model by using this command

```
include Query
```

now should every thing ready to use my custom method , but when I tried to call my method in the controller like that

```
def index
   @users= Users.custom(params[:query])
end
```

I got the error

```
undefined method `custom'
```

what I should do now ??

why i got this error  ??

Comment: I assume `Users.custom` is just a typo as it should be singular, did you restart your app?

Comment: This is just example , I think this is not the problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use concern for your module. Add your file in app/models/concerns.

```
# app/models/concerns/query.rb
module Query
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do

        #you can use a scope
        scope :my_query, ->(just_a_param){ .... }
    end

    module ClassMethods
        #or a method
        def self.another_query
            where(....)
        end
    end
end
```

Of course you need to include the module in your model. As concern erd default in rails, you no longer need to change config autoload paths.

Comment: when using a concern and defining class methods, you should create another module inside the included module called ClassMethods, and define instance methods there. Have a look at the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Answer (score 0):

As a class method, you'll need the "self."

```
def self.custom my_query
  self.where(my_query) 
end
```

EDIT: If you want this in all ActiveRecord models, you can add it as an initializer

```
#config/initializers/active_record_extensions.rb

class ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.custom my_query
    self.where(my_query) 
  end

end
```

If you just want this on a single class, a concern would work.

Comment: I tried it but still get the same error  undefined method `custom'

Comment: You can confirm the constant is available in `rails c`.  In rails console, type 'Query', you may see a more useful error.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no reference given between your class Users and your method custom. First: if Users refers to a Ruby on Rails class it is probably called User (see also comment of japed). So change the call. Next, your User class must inherited from ActiveRecord else it would not be aware of the existence of 'where'. For details check your app/models/user.rb

Then Swards' suggestion should work for you. Stop your application and restart. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the true way to make it

First my impropriety was the include that I set in the model
It should be `extend Query`

then it will work well

so the true code will be

create your method file under this path `lib/query.rb`

then set this code in it

```
module Query

  def custom my_query
    self.where(my_query)
  end

end
```

then added this code in this file `lib/application.rb`

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

then extend the method in the model by using this command

```
extend Query
```

and in your controller query  you can use the method like that

```
def index
   @users= Users.custom(params[:query])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, not exactly the 'Rails way', but using some sort of decorator pattern:

```
@user = CustomQuery.find_for(User.find(params[:search])).perform!

class CustomQuery

  attr_reader :params, :klass

  def initialize(klass)
    @params = params
    @klass = klass
  end

  def self.find_for(params)
    CustomQuery.new(params)
    find_model_for(params.tap {})
  end

  def perform!
    return params unless params.nil?
    klass.all
  end

  def find_model_for(klass)
    @klass = klass    
  end

end
```

Answer (score -4):

While I'm not sure about the process to create a global method, I can tell that your Ruby code is not valid:

```
  def custom my_query
    self.where(my_query)
  end
```

It would need to be:

```
  def custom (my_query)
    self.where(my_query)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Ilrein but I'm also tried but when i was tying but this is not the problem , thanks for tying to help me

Comment: Nope. It is valid Ruby. Horrible at times, but valid.

Comment: Parenthesis around parameters are optional.  Recommended for style purposes, but that code is perfectly valid.